# How do I check BlueTooth connection status in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am having trouble with checking the connection status of a *BlueTooth* socket. The following code causes a Runtime error:

```
public boolean Connected(){
    boolean connected = false;
    if(socket.isConnected()) {
        connected = true;
    }else{
        connected = false;
    }

    return connected;
}
```

The logcat prints the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2900): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.isConnected
```

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like - such as where you declare your variable `socket`?

Comment: What Android version are you running this on? [`isConnected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#isConnected()) was introduced in API 14 (ICS).

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkjxa5srv9zfr41/sovf.java here is the rest of the code. I guess the problem is, that I'm running it on android 2.3.7. How could I check the connection under API 14?

Comment: you should make a support library for checking if a bluetooth device is connected for less than 14, I don't know why this hasn't been done.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with java/android. I don't really know how should I make that lib. But I'll google it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When socket.connect is called, it blocks until the connection is made or it throws an exception. If you get an exception, then you know you are not connected.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I establish the connection at the start of the activity, and disconnect it at the end of the activity. So, I'd like to check it between the two events. Because, the other device maybe stopped the connection, or something went wrong.

Comment: When you transmit data, if you get an exception, then you already know that something's wrong. You can take necessary steps from there.

Comment: So, I should use outputStream.write(bytes) in a try/catch block?

Comment: Yes. If you can't transmit data, you should do something about it. Check what kind of exceptions might be thrown.